# Losing session on ajax call

Tags: ajax, session, ruby-on-rails-4, csrf

So, in our app, we are doing few ajax call to our api(same domain, same server).

Typically those ajax calls are 'autosuggestion', upload picture, ...

It worked fine on rails 3, it works fine rails 4 in local env(localhost) but on our dev server it doesn't work anymore.

I was suspecting that something was up with csrf but I have the csrf token in the  of the pages and the ajax call is sending a the token also.

However here is what I have in the logs

```
Started GET "/api/v1/services/get_suggestions/289" for 50.16.6.85 at 2014-03-13 18:40:24 +0000
Processing by Api::V1::ServiceController#get_suggestions as JSON
  Parameters: {"service_id"=>"289"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 2ms
Started GET "/user/sign_in.json" for 50.16.6.85 at 2014-03-13 18:40:24 +0000
Processing by SessionsController#new as JSON
Redirected to http://dev.myapp.com/
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 466ms (ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you're session is associated with another subdomain? The CSRF token is associated with the session and the session could be associated with a specific subdomain.

For example if your session is on the domain myapp.com domain

But the request is made to dev.myapp.com the CSRF token is invalid because it's only valid for the session on the domain http://maypp.com.